# Проблема с hover

Tags: jquery, hover

Если курсор наведён на `.blue_block`, то `.red_block` применяет `.active`, если курсор отведён от `.blue_block`, то `.active` удаляется.

И вроде бы всё работает:

1. Наведите курсор на синий блок, красный становится зелёным;
2. Отведите курсор от синего блока и возвращается красный

Но проблема в том, что только при отведении вне блоков работает событие `hover`, т.е. наведите курсор на зелёный блок и событие не сработает, если же за пределы него, то сработает.

https://jsfiddle.net/3ya48b8q/1/

```js
var blue_block_h = 0;

$('.blue_block').hover(function() {
  blue_block_h = 1;
}, function() {
  blue_block_h = 0;
});

$('body').hover(function() {
  if(!blue_block_h) {
    $('.red_block').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.red_block').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.blue_block {
  background: blue;
  padding: 25px
}

.red_block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red
}

.red_block.active {
  background: green !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="blue_block">test</div>
  <div class="red_block"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

В чём проблема? Прописывать все элементы так, не вариант, их может быть много:

```
$('body, .red_block').hover(function() {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Cобытие срабатывает не когда отводите с блоков, а когда наводите на body, очень странно вы используете hover body. Почему не вписать все действия в hover blue? или если надо сделать дропдаун то оборачивайте все в один блок и без js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените таким кодом (поменяно `body` на `blue_block`) - все работает

```
var blue_block_h = 0;

$('.blue_block').hover(function() {
  blue_block_h = 1;
}, function() {
  blue_block_h = 0;
});

$('.blue_block').hover(function() {
  if(!blue_block_h) {
    $('.red_block').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.red_block').addClass('active');
  }
});
```